# OSM To Postgis & WGS84 problems

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, wgs84, osm2pgsql

I’m trying to import OpenStreetMap (OSM) data into postGIS it doesn’t appear to be working in that features do not appear to be in the correct place..

Using the QGIS  OSM add in  and a coastal shape file imported into PostGIS setting the SRS to 4326 on import (all my data uses WGS84 Longitude & Latitude) the two data sets are in the same space.

Importing  the OSM data set  into postgis with the following code & adding it as a QGIS layer I would expect lines points etc of the OSM file & PostGIS layers to be adjacent if not on top of each other but they are not, 
I can’t actually see the coastal shapefile & the OSM PostGIS layer together without turning one layer off and selecting zoom to layer on the other.

BTW I have attempted to use the -E 4326  switch with out -m but it failed
So what am I doing wrong?

```
createDB osm
createlang plpgsql osm –U username 
psql –U username –d osm  -f /path/to/postgis1.5/postgis.sql
psql –U username –d osm  -f /path/to/postgis1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql
psql –U username –d osm  -f /path/to/osm2pgsql/900913.sql

osm2pgsql –S /path/to/osm2pgsql/default.style –U username –d osm  -l –c –m /path/to/ cambridgeshire.osm.bz2
```

I then tried following the instructions on http://spatialmounty.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/transform-osm-data-in-postgis-to-wgs84.html to re-project the data to WGS84 Long Lat it failed at The first line with invalid SRID

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn( 'planet_osm_line', 'geom_wgs84', 4326, 'LINESTRING', 2);
```

My database  has the following tables

```
Geography_columns  view
Geometry_columns table
Planet_osm_line table
Planet_osm_point table
Planet_osm_polygon table
Planet_osm_roads table
Spatial_ref_sys table
```

Can somebody give me the steps / syntax i need to follow to accurately import OSM data into PostGIS so that it uses ESPG:4326?

Any one know of any ground truth data I can use to test the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only the `-l` parameter and drop `-m` in your command. From the `osm2pgsql` help:

```
-l|--latlong    Store data in degrees of latitude & longitude.
-m|--merc       Store data in proper spherical mercator (default)
```

Comment: I created a new DB and Running the command without the –m switch results in


<code>    Osm2pgsql SVN version 0.80.0 (32bit id space)

    Using projection SRS4326 (LatLong)

    Setting up table: planet_osm_point

    Notice: table: “planet_osm_point” does not exist, skipping


    Notice: table: “planet_osm_point_tmp” does not exist, skipping


    SELECT AddGeometryColumn( 'planet_osm_point, 'way’, 4326, 'POINT’, 2);


    Failed: ERROR:  AddGeometryColumns() – invalid SRID</code>

Answer (score 3):

Just done the process for Cambridge. [This is the fastest method]

Using PostGIS 2.0 (pgAdmin postgres SQL Tools 1.14)

Downloaded the Cambridge OpenStreetMap data from here:

http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/europe/great_britain/england/

selected Cambridge note the cambridgeshire.shp.zip  01-May-2012 06:08   11M ESRI Shapefile (**EPSG:4326**), zipped

Loaded into PostGIS with no changes to the data using the 'PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager'
[image]

Then loaded the data into QGIS

[image]

Loading this will confirm that the WGS84 is being used.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a couple of issues with your approach
1st i'm using postGresql 8.4 and PostGIS 1.5 so only the bash shp2psql is available 
2nd Cambridgeshire is my test data set can you get a world shape file?
3rd i'm only using qgis to view the data I really need to store the data with an srs ESPG 4326 so any data analysis can be carried out within the database.
Thanks for your suggestions anyway it has given me food for thought.

Comment: This approach can be done for the entire world - the data is stored natively from the osm data source as ESPG 4326. Would recommend to anyone to upgrade to PostGIS 2 there are some much more useful spatial functions in there now.

Comment: Use the OSM2SQL to append the data into the database http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/ - Example osm2pgsql -c -d gis -U postgres -W -H localhost -P 5433 N:\Geo_data\OpenStreetMap\OSM_xml\yourOSM_filename.bz2

Answer (score 2):

Hi All I've managed to this I apologize for answering my own question but thought others might find it use full

create a database but DO NOT use the 900913.sql The code below shows the steps i made

```
createDB osm
createlang plpgsql osm –U username 
psql –U username –d osm  -f /path/to/postgis1.5/postgis.sql
psql –U username –d osm  -f /path/to/postgis1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql

osm2pgsql –S /path/to/osm2pgsql/default.style –U username –d osm  -l –c /path/to/ cambridgeshire.osm.bz2
```

Thank you for your contributions as they led me to this answer

Answer (score 1):

This is harder than it sounds - I made some [notes](http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/openstreetmap/osm.html) on my (abortive) attempts to get the whole of OSM into a postgis data base which may help you get started.

The bottom line is I gave up and went and used a different [data set](http://naturalearthdata.com).

Comment: were you not able to use osmosis for this?  BTW you data set link should be http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

Comment: I lost interest and moved on :-)